# Polymer 1.0 access parent e.model in nested repeats

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="first">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{first}}" as="second">
        <span on-tap="test">{{second}}</span>
    </template>
</template>

items: [["1","2"],["3","4"]],
test: function (e) {
    // access e.model of first
}
```

Is it possible to access the e.model of the outer repeat loop? Just getting the object is not enough (altough this would be a start). I need the model variable to use push/pop on it. To my surprise e.model.first does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="firstRepeat" items="{{items}}" as="first">
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="secondRepeat" items="{{first}}" as="second">
        <span on-tap="test">{{second}}</span>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
  items: [["1","2"],["3","4"]],
  test: function (e) {
    // First model
    this.$.firstRepeat.modelForElement(e.target);

    // Second model
    this.$.secondRepeat.modelForElement(e.target);
  }
</script>
```